# How to make a default file browsing location for any third party tool having a browse button?

Tags: c#, variables, system

My problem is whenever i click browse button on any tool it opens it's own home location. Instead i want a specific location to open, which is of a Configuration management folder in somewhere other location than in it's home. Please help. I tried environment variable settings it doesn't work.

Comment: browse button on any third party tool should open my preferred location. is it possible?